# Batch input stops working for the second time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which asks me for a choice, when chosen, it then asks "are you sure"? If the answer is empty string and you press enter, it accepts it as yes, if your answer is "h" and enter is accepts is as no. However the problem is it doesn't work for the second time (when I press enter, it doesnt accept it as a yes), (the problem might be in `set /p`).

*You need to change the first part of the code if you want to look at it in your PC*

```
@echo off
@for %%a in ( C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ) do @if exist %%a:\TAM_IMAGES set The_Drive=%%a
@for %%b in ( C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ) do @if exist %%b:\DenemeJpg.bat set applyimage=%%b
REM @dir %The_Drive%:\TAM_IMAGES
REM @dir %applyimage%:\DenemeJpg.bat
cd /D %The_Drive%:\TAM_IMAGES
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:input
set count=100
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
  set /a count+=1
  echo !count:~-2!] %%a
)
set /a countMax=count-100
set "countNr=%count:~-2%"
<nul set /p "= Yuklemek istediginiz imaji seciniz " 
choice /c 1234567890 /n >nul
set first=%errorlevel:~-1%
<nul set /p "=%first%"
choice /c 1234567890 /n >nul
echo %errorlevel:~-1%
set ch=%first%%errorlevel:~-1%
REM echo [%file%] Imajini sectiniz.
set /a line=1%ch%-101

REM echo debug: ch=%ch%;CountNr=%countNr%;CountMax=%CountMax%,Line=%line%
if "%ch%" == "00" goto escape
if %ch% gtr %countMax% echo bad input&goto :input

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d^|more +%line%') do set "file=%%a"&goto :cont
:cont
SET /P KeyPressed=%file% imajini sectiniz, emin misiniz?
IF [%KeyPressed%] EQU [] goto devam
IF %KeyPressed% EQU h goto input
:devam
REM echo %ch% - %file% imajını sectiniz.
start "" %applyimage%:\DenemeJpg.bat 
REM %The_Drive%:\TAM_IMAGES\%file%

REM goto :eof
cmd /k

:escape
echo you choosed '00' for exit.
```

Comment: Pretty much straight away, I can see an issue, `cd %The_Drive%:…` should read `CD /D %The_Drive%:…`, because you are clearly changing drive as well as directory.

Comment: Why should it be the problem, its working fine. Im %98 sure its not the problem, its just for another case; its looking which drive has that folder and finding it. Its just working first time and it doesn't need to work for the second time because when you press "h" for you are going to ":input" part so it's not even working for the second time

Comment: It is a problem, open up a Command Prompt window, type `cd /?` press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. `CD` used alone, changes between directories on the same drive/volume, to also change drive/volume you need to use the `/D` option!

Comment: I get what you mean, you're right /D is necessary when it will work in real life. But for now its just in a test computer so it has only one drive. But i still added /D and nothing changed. There must be another problem in set /p part or another place

Comment: So in answer to your statement, it's working fine, you were wrong, because your command was too. What you need to understand is that in order for our members to assist you, they need to be able to reproduce the issue. To do that it's essential that they're using the problematic code, in as similar an environment as yourself. This means that if you provide code, it should be correct and work, if it is indeed unrelated to the issue you are reporting. You didn't do that, so I provided you with that correction. What you should have done, then, and now, is to edit your question code and correct it.

Comment: I think i didn't understand you but my all code is this and it is working perfectly except this issue so i'm here asking my question. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Please change your `cd` command to make it correct, I've told you what it should say, I've provided you with a method of reading the official usage information, to verify that I'm not just making it up, and I've explained it in more simple terms for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter nothing (just {ENTER}) at a `set /p` prompt, it doesn't clear the variable, but leaves it unchanged. If you reuse the code (`goto :input`), you need to clear the variable before `set /p`:

```
...
:cont
set "KeyPressed="
SET /P KeyPressed=%file% imajini sectiniz, emin misiniz?
IF [%KeyPressed%] EQU [] goto devam
IF %KeyPressed% EQU h goto input
...
```

I'd use the safer syntax `if "%KeyPressed" == ""` and `if /i "%KeyPressed" == "h"`.

Comment: also: are you aware, that if you enter anything else than nothing or `h`, your code execution will continue with `:devam`? Maybe replace `if /i "%KeyPressed" == "h" goto input` with just `goto input`.

Comment: Oh just realised u're right, why it's continuing? it must go only if its equal to "h"..

Comment: There is nothing to stop it. A label is just ignored by program flow (it serves as a jump-destination only, not as a break-point), Insert a `goto :somewhereElse` (or `goto :eof` to stop code execution)

Comment: Im trying to add `if NOT /i "%KeyPressed%" == "h" | "" goto input` but its not working

Comment: because it's a wrong syntax. See `if /?`.What's `| ""` supposed to do?

Comment: I tried to say keypressed not equal to h or empty string

Comment: `if` has no such things as `OR`or `AND`.

Comment: I made this and its working great. Now i need to clean that set /p variable and want to make 01=1 02=2 etc for first 9 choice ( i mean when i write only 1 and press enter it will go to 01)
`:cont
SET /P sec= "%file% imajini sectiniz; devam etmek icin <Enter> tusuna, menuye geri donmek icin "H" tusuna basiniz."
2>NUL CALL :durum_%sec%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE
EXIT /B

:durum_
 goto :devam
:durum_h
  goto :input

:DEFAULT_CASE
  ECHO Yanlis bir tusa bastiniz.
  goto :cont
:devam `

Comment: Did you try to `write only 1 and press enter`? It just doesn't work, as I described in the answer to your previous question: `Downside: You always have to enter both (all) digits ( like 01 for the first choice)`

Comment: I know it doesnt work, but i thought there might be a way. I respect your knowledge on batch script a lot so if you say there is no way for "only press 1 and enter" then i won't scratch it more.